# Count characters used in String

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a number - e.g: `1234` and another number `1112`

I want to count how many digits are used in the string. e.g for `1234`, I would get 4, as all digits are unique. As for `1112`, I would get 2, as there is only 1 and 2 in the string.

How do I achieve this using JavaScript?

Comment: loop over each one, creating an object with keys, then count the keys. Convert it to an array and make it unique. Loop over it and use indexOf.

Comment: I'd close it as Too Simple if I could. This is really basic, just read the manual.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/exL7mw5z/

Answer (score 0):

You can get an array of characters from the string, filter for duplicates, and count the length:

```
function countUsedDigits(n) {
    return n.split('').filter(function (item, index, self) {
        return self.indexOf(item) == index;
    }).length;
}

countUsedDigits("1234")       === 4;
countUsedDigits("1112")       === 2;
countUsedDigits("1213242353") === 5;
```